# Change font weight in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, text, fonts, editor, text-editor

i know in visual studio code we can change the font weight in settings.json but i can only change it to "bold", "900" has no effect. Is there any way to change the font weight like make it less bold ? Thank you everyone.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I69hh.png)

i tried "bold" and number, but it does not have any effect.